# How to setup port forwarding properly in FreeBsd 11?

Tags: freebsd, firewall, openvpn, vpn, port-forwarding

I have freebsd 11 on a server where I've installed openVPN and I need to setup VPN properly to put traffic through it. I can't connect to the internet anymore after I've established a connection with my server via VPN. The issue is port forwarding and I want to set it up via `/etc/pf.conf`.

Here's what I have:

```
sysctl net.inet.ip.forwarding  #=> net.inet.ip.forwarding: 1
```

And

```
$ cat /etc/rc.conf
ifconfig_vtnet0="dhcp"
openvpn_enable="YES"
openvpn_if="tun"
gateway_enable="YES"
```

And the openVPN config of the server:

```
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
```

Yet, the error I have on the server observed in its logs is:

```
MULTI: bad source address from client [x.x.x.x], packet dropped
```

What have I forgotten?

Comment: You are probably missing NAT on your public interface.

Comment: @RichardSmith, and?

Comment: Are you trying to put internet traffic through the VPN?

Comment: @RichardSmith, yes.

Comment: Ok, you need to turn on *network address translation* at the interface connected to the internet (vtnet0?), as you are forwarding between private and public address spaces. I do not use `pf` myself, so I cannot give you a more specific answer.